# Why find the spectra of a differential operator?

Tags: functional-analysis, ordinary-differential-equations, numerical-methods, eigenvalues-eigenvectors

I know that there are many results about the spectra of compact differential operators but I really don't understand the significance of them. Let's consider, for simplicity, the differential operator:

$Ly = p(x)y'' + q(x)y' + r(x)$ where $p(x),q(x),r(x)$ satisfy some regularity conditions.

If I am interested in solving, or understanding the behavior of solutions $y$ to $Ly = 0$ on $x \in [0,1]$ subject to $y(0) = \alpha, y(1) = \beta$, what benefit would I get by solving for the eigenvalues and eigenfunctions of $L$?

In other words, why would solving the associated eigenvalue problem be beneficial if, to begin with, you are not solving an eigenvalue problem nor any problem that looks like $Ly = \lambda y + f$? (For these types of problems I do see an explanation why solving for $Lv = \lambda v$ could be handy.)

Also, can anyone point me to references for solving the eigenvalues/eigenfunctions numerically of non-constant coefficient operators? The examples I've seen in books only deal with constant coefficients.

Suggestions appreciated.

Comment: Diagonalizing the differential operator is the same as diagonalizing a matrix. Linear equations are then much easier to solve.

Comment: @PeterSheldrick I get that point. However, these basis functions $\phi_i(x)$ do not satisfy $L \phi_i(x) = 0$, rather, they satisfy $L\phi_i = \lambda \phi_i$. Hene, if we want to solve $Ly = 0$ and express $y = \sum_i c_i \phi_i$, how would that help us?

Comment: @PeterSheldrick, and DisintegratingByParts Thanks for the help! Any ideas on how to numerically obtain the eigenvalues/ eigenfunctions? I am thinking of discretizing the operator using finite differences to obtain a matrix and computing the eigenvalues/eigenfunctions of this matrix. But what shall the boundary conditions for the eigenvalue problem be? Should they be the same boundary conditions as my operator $L$ or should they be homogeneous?

Answer (score 1):

If you want to solve $Ly=0$ subject to $y(0)=\alpha, y(1)=\beta$, then you can reduce this to an inhomogeneous problem with homogeneous conditions by letting
$$
          y= w-\alpha x-\beta(1-x).
$$
Then $0=Ly=Lw-\alpha Lx-\beta L(1-x)$ gives an equivalent equation for $w$:
$$
               Lw = (\alpha+\beta)Lx+\beta L1,\;\; w(0)=w(1)=0.
$$
This inhomogeneous equation can be solved using the eigenfunctions of $L$ with zero endpoint conditions.